# Vertical alignment in table-cell together with floating div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, css-tables

I have the following (sample) html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TH-Alignment</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        th {
            border: 1px solid #333;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        div.sb {
            float: right;
            width: 4px;
            height: 26px;
            background-color: #999;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <colgroup>
            <col width="120" />
            <col width="120" />
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <div class="sb"></div>
                    <div>Heading 1</div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <div>Heading 2</div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

The div in the second column is vertically centered, the div in the first column not
(always positioned at the top of the table-cell). Why does the floating div inside
column one influence the vertical alignment of the other div within the table cell?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 good question. Expanded a bit on your code (some height on the th, some display on divs, and a few borders for debugging), see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mk7su/3/). It seems the content in the first th *is* v-aligned, but the first div is at the top of the line for some reason...

Comment: The answer, I think, lies [in this **W3 table layout spec**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#height-layout). If no one beats me to it I may try to conjure a real answer and demo when I have time.

Comment: I wonder if `<div>` is allowed inside `<th>` reading http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.6

Answer (score 4):

If you expand the height for the `th`, you will notice that elements are still vertically aligned to the middle.

See this [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/CP5Wx/)!

The issue here is the `line-height`.

Since you've got more that one element on that first `th`, and one of those elements has a `height` defined, all elements are aligned to the middle of the `th` but between them, they are aligned to the height of their current `line-height`, which is not defined and being calculated either by the `font-size` or a parent element definition.

Since your floated element has a `height` of `26px`, it grows down, but the element with the text as no `line-height` defined so it's `height` is equal to the `font-size` provided by the text inside, thus never getting to the middle of its floated sibling.

**To fix this, you need to use:**

```
line-height: 26px;
```

*To set a `line-height` equal to the `height` of your floated element, thus aligning the text to the middle of the floated element and solving the visual aspect of the vertical alignment.*

---

**See this** [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/CP5Wx/1/) with that **working solution**!

---

**Note:**
One element is not affecting the other as you suspect, they just don't have enough declarations to have a coherent alignment among them!

By default text and images are aligned to the `baseline`, if no `line-height` is given, the `baseline` is the `font-size`.

Comment: +1 as far as I can tell this should be the accepted answer :D